# Get ListView Items dynamically

Tags: java, android, dynamic, android-layout

I've added some items dynamically like this:

```
position = position + 1;
LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutTest);
TimePicker tpAux = new TimePicker(MyClass.this);
tpAux.setIs24HourView(true);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                 layoutParams.setMargins(0, 12, 0, 0);
myLayout.addView(tpAux, position, layoutParams);
```

That code throws when a button is pressed.

The question is, how to get all TimePicker (in this case) items that were created at run time when another button is pressed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not understanding what you are trying to achieve here. This doesn't look like code you would use in a `ListView` at all?

Comment: well, that code is the code i have in the "on click" event (that one generating TimePickers). I would like to take information of all TimePickers when another button is pressed. The problem is that i can't `findViewById(R.id.TimePickerID)`, because timePickers are created dynamically, and i can't create ID and assing them with `setId` function, because i don't know how many TimePickers will be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using myLayout.getChildCount() and myLayout.getChildAt(int)?

Comment: oh, that knowledge will be awesome for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use [`setTag()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29) with a unique hashcode/int or something else? I can't really understand your question more than that.

From the docs:

> Sets a tag associated with this view and a key. A tag can be used to mark a view in its hierarchy and does not have to be unique within the hierarchy. Tags can also be used to store data within a view without resorting to another data structure. The specified key should be an id declared in the resources of the application to ensure it is unique (see the ID resource type).